# How can I install windows movie maker 2 using wine?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, wine, video-editor

So I looked on winehq today to see if windows movie maker works on ubuntu, since I feel Kdenlive eats up too much memory and space on my hard drive and it seems to run [properly](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33096).  The only problem is I cannot seem to find any sort of portable or installation file to get movie maker on my pc.  Can anyone help me with this?

Using Lubuntu 17.04

Comment: Have you tried openshot? http://www.openshot.org/

Comment: No, i'll try it tonight I guess.

Comment: Windows Movie Maker is actually rated 'garbage' for most of the versions.  As well, it's what comes packaged in Windows and I don't think has its own installation file.  I would believe that this is one of the few things that cannot properly be used in Wine.

Comment: Well I did find an installation of 2.0 on 4shared last night and it did boot up.  The only problem was the most vital part, that is, actually importing videos.

Comment: I recommend check the alternatives in Windows world. Probably more than one runs on wine: http://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-windows-movie-maker-alternative

Comment: Are you asking how to install a tool on wine (which is on topic) or where to download the windows installer for it (which is off topic)?

Comment: You edited your title, but the body is still about getting an installation file